# "oauth2client.transport : Refreshing due to a 401" what exactly this log mean?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow

I setup a job on google cloud dataflow, and it need more than 7 hours to make it done. My Job ID is 2016-10-10_09_29_48-13166717443134662621. It didn't show any error in pipeline. Just keep logging out "oauth2client.transport : Refreshing due to a 401". Is there any problem of my workers or there is something wrong. If so, how can I solve it?

Comment: 401 means "Not authorised"... Sounds like you're failing to authenticate something properly

Answer (score 2):

As a general approach, you should try running the pipeline locally, using the `DirectPipelineRunner` on a small dataset to debug your custom transformations.

Once that passes, you can use the Google Cloud Dataflow UI to investigate the pipeline state. You can particularly look at `Elements Added` field in the `Step` tab to see whether your transformations are producing output.

---

In this particular job, there's a step that doesn't seem to be producing output, which normally indicates an issue in the user code.

Comment: Indeed, the job appears to not be making progress - looks like processing of some records is hanging. Right now I recommend to cancel the pipeline. The best way to debug this is to run it locally first using direct runner, but you can also use logging. Additionally, I recommend turning on autoscailng - this way Dataflow can shut down the idle workers (one of the workers is idle), saving resources and cost.